# How Do I get a Six pack

Tags: running, weight-loss, workout, body-fat, muscle-gain

My name is Jake and I'm 15 years old. I'm 5'10" and 140 pounds. I have been working out in gym for 2 weeks now and as I calculated my body fat percentage is around 14%-15%. My goal is to get a six pack and build up some muscles (Chest, Biceps,etc.) How can I get a six pack? Do I need to lower my body fat percentage to 10% by running and cycling or do I just workout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips on having six packs and losing fat and keeping the muscles I have](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/18750/tips-on-having-six-packs-and-losing-fat-and-keeping-the-muscles-i-have)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a helpful visual guide on what 10% looks like:

[image]

As you can see it is possible to be 10% without a 6 pack. You need to do targeted strength exercises to get it. Your calculated maximum weight potential is 185 lbs at 10% body fat, based on Martin [Berkhan's formula](http://www.leangains.com/2010/12/maximum-muscular-potential.html) so you can put on more weight and still looked ripped as hell. But that weight must be muscle.

Rather than go into a full explanation of each of the below I suggest you pop over to reddit/r/fitness and [read their wiki](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fitness/wiki/)

I'm guessing you want to be aesthetic due to your post. Before you can do targeted workouts on being aesthetic you need to develop a strong base.

Here is your 3 year plan:

- Read up and complete the StartingStrength or Stronglifts 5x5 program. Add the accessory ab work, keep this level of ab workout forever.
- Calculate your TDEE/Macros and start trying to plan your calorie intake where possible through a diet plan (you are 15, you might be able to influence your parents choices).
- Read Mark Rippetoe's book in-between sets.
- Learn about periodization.
- After 6-12 months of your first chosen program you will be stalling a lot on nearly all lifts. You should then reassess your options and your diet.

  - If you want to be strong like [mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haf%C3%BE%C3%B3r_J%C3%BAl%C3%ADus_Bj%C3%B6rnsson) then move towards 5/3/1, Texas Method, BigButBoring, Greyskull LP. (more on reddit wiki).
  - If you want to be aesthetic like [Zzyz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aziz_Shavershian) then move towards a plan like PPL, ICF, PHAT.
- Re-introduce Cardio into your workout if you haven't already. Cardio is great for maintaining a healthy heart and **assisting** in dropping body fat percentage.
- Now you have a pretty good base of strength and should have visible muscles. Hopefully you will be hovering around the 15-20% bf mark due to your eating lots so you can continue to progress on lifts. Adjust your diet onto a cut and maintain your lifts.
- Cut to 10-15%.
- 'Mire your 6pack

> “Everybody wants to be a bodybuilder, but nobody wants to lift no
>   heavy-ass weights.” ― Ronnie Coleman

Comment: *Mark Rippetoe wouldn't be impressed with that spelling ;)

Comment: Fixed. Pls don't kill me Mark ;_;

Comment: Additionally, the "6" of the abdominal muscle structure is genetically determined by the fascia that helps structure and brace the abdominals. Genetically a person could have 2-8 in almost any variation you can think of.